# Return complex object in REST Web API call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API POST method that excepts a custom complex object `MyObjectRequest` as a parameter and returns a custom complex object `MyObjectResponse`.  The `MyObjectResponse` object has custom complex object `Token` as a property.

```
public class MyObjectRequest
{
   public string AppName { get; set; }
   public string Username { get; set; }
   public string Password { get; set; }
   public string AppIdentifier { get; set; }
}

public class MyObjectResponse
{
   public bool Authenticated { get; set; }
   public Token AccessToken { get; set; }
}

public class Token
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string ExpirationDate { get; set; }
}
```

I have Web API controller where when the user makes a HTTP POST call, I want to return the `MyObjectResponse`.

```
public class MyCustomController : Controller
{
    public MyObjectResponse Post([FromBody] MyObjectRequest request)
    {
        //do my work here
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way of making my `MyCustomController` API signature?

Answer (score 15):

What you have certainly can work. I tend to wrap those objects in the `HttpResponseMessage` like below:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] MyObjectRequest request)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) // and if you have any other checks
    {
        var myObjectResponse = new MyObjectResponse(); 
        // In your case, this will be result of some service method. Then...

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, myObjectResponse);
    }
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);       
}

[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage Update([FromBody] UserModel userModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var myObjectResponse = new MyObjectResponse();
        // In your case, this will be result of some service method. Then...
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
    }
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}

[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
{
    var myObjectResponse = GetObjectFromDb(id);
    // In your case, this will be result of some service method. Then...
    if(myObjectResponse == null)
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, myObjectResponse);            
}
```

This way the client can just look at the status code and decide what to do with the response without actually trying to deserialize it. You can get more info on HttpStatusCodes at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode.aspx).

They have added more methods such as `ApiController.Ok` in WebApi2. For more information, you can take a look at this [ASP.NET WEB API overview page](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/action-results).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is perfectly fine as an api signature

Comment: Thanks.  Would this work in a iOS and Android environment.  Plan on this being consumed from mobile applications.

Comment: It should. The advantage of web api is that is does content negotiation based on content type in the request header. That means that you can request it as JSON, XML or whatever other standard format you need on the client side.